# Sharing DocumentFile using FileProvider

Tags: android, file-sharing, storage-access-framework

if I want to share `sourceFile` of type `File`, I use FileProvider with authorities. Snippet:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.putExtra(
    Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(
        context,
        context.applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
        sourceFile
    )
)
intent.type = "audio/ogg"
startActivity(context, Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.share_audio)), null)
```

What is a proper way to do that if `sourceFile` is a `DocumentFile` instead of `File`?

I couldn't fnd any sort of replacement for `getUriForFile` that works with `DocumentFile`. At the moment I just copy file to cache and then share it from there, but I guess there should be a better way.

Comment: Often its enough to just use the uri and put a flag FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.

Comment: For the rest you could make your own file provider by extending ContentProvider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is a proper way to do that if sourceFile is a DocumentFile instead of File?

You do not need `FileProvider` in that scenario. Instead, call `getUri()` on the `DocumentFile`, and use that `Uri` in your `Intent`.

Comment: Thats wrong, sometimes you might have DocumentFile.fromFile(file) then the getUri wont work in an Intent.

Comment: @ueen: "sometimes you might have DocumentFile.fromFile(file)" -- generally, that means that you have a `File`, as you called `fromFile()` with a `File`. The question is about the case where you do not have a `File`.

Comment: Yea but if you only get a DocumentFile (from a callback for example) that might be derived from DocumentFile.fromFile(file) or not (!), you dont know - using getUri then you get a FileUriExposedException

Answer (score -1):

```
Uri fileUri = null;
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                                    try {
                                        fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".myfileprovider", file);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                                }

                                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                share.setType("audio/ogg");
                                share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share"), 201);
```